# Get the rest of the mayo from the jar?

Tags: food, kitchen, container

You, know when you've almost used up the jar of mayonnaise, but there is still a bit more left on the sides of the jar, and on the bottom...

What is the best way to obtain that last bit of mayo from the jar with minimum effort? (The mayo should still be edible and good to use.)

I am aware that it depends on the jar, however, let's take the standard jar type. eg.:

[image: Hellman's mayo jar]

Comment: @vladiz, I don't think so, because the other question was specifically addressing bottles with a neck too narrow to fit most implements inside.  The traditional mayonnaise jar has a much wider neck.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. See my edits to the other question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a rubber spatula or plate scrapper.

[image]

When I worked in the restaurant business, one of them claimed that their policy of scrapping down the insides of cans and jars with a rubber spatula saved the company a million dollars a year...

Comment: This is what I was going to say.  You might add to find one whose contours fit a mayo jar corner, or one with a more flexible edge; both of those attributes can vary.